# Mysql query on SQL file

Tags: php, database, mysqli

How  can I use mysql querys on SQL file on custom path? File contain db or table.

For example like this:

```
// file contain db
$Mysqli = new mysqli('../MyFolder/MyDb.sql', 'User', 'Pass');
$Mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM Table");

// file contain table 
$Mysqli = new mysqli('../MyFolder/MyTable.sql', 'User', 'Pass');
$Mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM Table");
```

Comment: What exactly should these files contain? Between your two examples, there's no difference besides the file name. How should PHP distinguish the two cases???

Comment: Two SQL file that one contain db and other contain table only.

Comment: You don't understand how databases work. Besides, the file formats for MySQL databases are .frm, .myd and .myi

Comment: Looking for SQLite perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The .sql file contains SQL commands; you will need to run it to create your database, and then you can use mysqli to connect to that database.

Comment: No, i would use SQL file without create it!

Comment: Wherever the SQL **comes from**, it contains instructions you must execute against the MySQL engine in order to persist.